# Why has this runeword failed?

Tags: diablo-ii

I am a ladder character on normal difficulty and got this for my hireling:

[image: Cropped screenshot showing a tooltip for a socketed bow]

The name of the bow was: `Short Battle Bow` in gray. I got this runeword from [Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/runewords-110.shtml), the name is `Edge`.

I don't get it though, all that happened was the name changed to `Gemmed Short Battle Bow`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you sure that it is a ladder character? They recently did the ladder reset and maybe your status has changed?

Comment: @Rapida - I was about to ask the same thing.

Comment: I created the character after the reset, and yes I am sure it is ladder.

Comment: Wait, I just went for double check and I saw that it doesn't say ladder anymore. I don't get it, I am sure I created the character as ladder!

Comment: @Rapida Could it be that the game requires that you finish on at least normal difficulty first, and then be able to play on ladder? I mean I started the game on a fresh account, could it be that I didn't even have the option to play on ladder?

Comment: You don't need to beat the game to make a ladder character. I can tell you this from personal experience.

Comment: @Wipqozn, would you suggest I start over and play the ladder? Is it that more exciting? Or if I continue to nightmare and hell, it would eventually be the same?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/runewords-110.shtml):

"The following Rune Words will only work on the Battle.net Realms for Ladder Characters only. They will not work for single or open characters or non-ladder characters"

It sounds like your character is no longer a ladder character. The ladder was reset on October 25, 2011. All previously ladder characters were moved to non-ladder.

Comment: I created my character after the reset. In fact the only reason I started playing was the reset. The character is ladder and in fact the game I created on Battle.net

Comment: @Shahbaz - wow, that's insane. I hope someone can help you out. I'm going to leave my answer so that people know about the ladder reset.

Comment: I went to check, and it wasn't in fact ladder! I am surprised because I went to play this game just to start the ladder!!! Could it be that I have a fresh account, and you cannot start ladder unless you have finished the game once?

Comment: Or that since I killed diablo and went over to expansion, I didn't play for a week and it threw me out of ladder?

Comment: Unless you started the character before the ladder reset, then your character should be ladder. The only other thing I can think of is that you may have accidentally unchecked the 'ladder character' box before you started. Well, I'm glad you figured out why it wasn't working :)

Comment: +1 This is a small detail I think the majority of users would miss (I know I did)

Comment: I am starting to think between switching from my favorite Necro to Trying out Druid I finally missed the ladder check. Ouch! So, you think I'm missing out on much? I'm almost finished with Normal, would it be worth it if I start over again with ladder? Or the ladder specials are not that great so I continue to nightmare?